# Is one legally entitled to hate members of a given religious sect, or to verbally declare that they do?

Tags: england-and-wales, freedom-of-speech

Presumably it is not legal to declare that they are scum, or worthless, or hellbound, etc. But is there not a fundamental difference when it comes to professing one's own personal sentiments?

Comment: It's [illegal to incite religious hatred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_and_Religious_Hatred_Act_2006) and more generally to [encourage crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encouraging_or_assisting_a_crime_in_English_law) (which replaced the old offence of inciting violence). It's not illegal simply to hate, but you'll have to do more research to find what exactly is illegal.

Comment: Seems like this comes close to duplicating many prior questions you've asked on related issues.

Comment: Sorry, my brain works in redundant ways sometimes as it ruminates on things.

Answer (score -3):

### Yes

Your thoughts and your words are yours and not subject to legal sanction.

Comment: thoughts... yes. Words... not so much. Words can be defamation or hate speech, which can be subject to legal action.

Comment: And others have the right what they think of you, obviously.